# How does vue routing make the 404 page jump to the outside site?

Tags: vue-router4

A common configuration is this:

```
{path:'/*', name:'404', component:()=>import('@/views/404.vue')},
```

This will jump to a vue page, but now I want to jump to a public 404 page outside the site, how do I do it?

Tried this, doesn't work:

```
{path:'/*', redirect:'http://*.com/404.html'},
```

The current method is to enter 404.vue first, and then run window.location.href="http://...."

I want to ask the big guys, can you set it directly in the routing table?

Answer (score 2):

Use this code in your router

```
{path:'*', name:'404', redirect:()=>{ window.location.href="some-url"}}
```

or

```
{path:'*', name:'404', component:()=> {window.location.href="some-url"}}
```

or if you want your component, instead of using redirect use your 404 vue component in your router

```
{path:'*', name:'404', component:()=>import('@/views/404.vue')}
```

Then in your 404.vue component in beforeCreate Lifecycle Hooks add this code

```
<script>
 export default {
  beforeCreate() {
    window.location.href = 'some_url'
  },
 
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems impossible.

But you can write components directly in the route here.

```
{path:'/*', name:'404', component: function(){window.location.href="http://sf.gg"}}
```